# Set vagrant virtualbox process priority

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have a vagrant virtualbox vm that runs better when the process priority is set to Below Normal. Currently this can be manually done by setting the  VBoxSvc.exe priority to Below Normal before running the VM. The VM's inherit the property and run well. Can the priority of the VM be set when it starts automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, within the Vagrant file before the VMs are created i start a VBoxSVC process with a given priority.  When the VMs are started they inherit the priority of VBoxSVC. Below is the command used to start VBoxSVC.

```
`start \"VBoxSVC\" /#{@priority} #{@vboxsvc_location}`
```

Comment: Is this still working? I tested with virtualbox 5.2.26. While VBoxSVC did have the priority changed, the VBoxHeadless processes created are still at Normal priority...